# Почему не работают колеса?[Unity C#]

Tags: unity3d

Есть корпус и 4 цилиндра.Они крутятся при помощи transform.Rotate.На цилиндрах есть Mesh Collider.Почему при вращении  колес максимум, что может делать машина-слегка дергаться на месте?На корпусе стоит Rigidbody
P.S От Wheel Collider машину неистово колбасит при касании с террейном.Ставил еще Box Collider, но машина и на ннм не едет, сцепления нет, а машина прыгает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так-так-так. Вы, верно, не совсем понимаете, что делаете. `Transform.Rotate` будет вращать ваш объект - это верно. Но это вращение никакого отношения к физике не имеет. Тем более если вы делаете это в `Update`.

Чтобы вращать что-то физически, вам нужно использовать доступные методы на `Rigidbody`. Т.е. `Rigidbody.AddTorque`.

Пример:

```
// Будет вращать тело вокруг вертикальной оси
GetComponent<RigidBody>().AddTorque(transform.up * torque);
```

`AddTorque` принимает два параметра - `Vector3` и `ForceMode`. Однако второй по умолчанию установлен в `ForceMode.Force`. Вы можете также использовать `ForceMode.Impulse`. Справка юнити: [тык](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html). Видосик: [тык](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/adding-physics-torque).

В интернетике достаточно уроков по этой теме, я лишь дал наводку.

Ах да. Еще, все вызовы к `Rigidbody` желательно (настоятельно рекомендуется) делать в `FixedUpdate` - т.е. прямо перед проходом физического движка. Вот.

Да, да, и еще. Если у вас машина прыгает от `WheelCollider`'ов, то значит вы их неправильно настроили. Помнится, на старых версиях юнити значения параметров измерялись тысячами, а потом славные ребята переделали и параметры измерялись единицами. Или наоборот... Но что-то такое было. Так что может вы настраивали по старому туториалу? Проверьте массы. Соизмеримы ли они с реальными? Посмотрите какие-то новые туториалы. Думаю, вы справитесь. Не изобретайте велосипед)

Comment: Кстати, юнити измеряет массу в килограммах?

Comment: @JetFly он измеряет массу, как и расстояние, в некоторых условных единицах. Для себя вы можете их интерпретировать как метры, килограммы, миллиметры и прочее. Удобно строить мир, когда 1 юнит - 1 метр. Но иногда бывает так, что 1 юнит - 1 см удобнее (к примеру, для какой-то игры про насекомых). Так и с массой. Я написал "соизмеримы ли они с реальными", но имел в виду " соизмеримы ли они друг с другом". Т.е. если вы условно жесткость представляете в н/кг, то массу условно должны представлять в кг. И соотношения масс между объектами должны быть сопоставимы с реальными. Как-то так

Comment: То есть,в Юнити абстрактная система измерения, выдумай сам и сам пользуйся этим

Comment: @JetFly А как вы себе представляете систему измерения в килограммах?) просто вы сами выбираете значение, с которым вам легко работать. Но по умолчанию гравитация выставлена в 10, что примерно равно земной, измеряемой в единицах СИ. Т.е. 10Н/кг. Так что могу предположить, что использовать единицы СИ - метры, килограммы, секунды - правильно.

Comment: Я примерно это и имел ввиду

Comment: Поменял, теперь машина игнорирует коллайдеры

Comment: @JetFly что именно поменяли?)